# iOS/Swift: Custom UIGestureRecognizer that detect spin motion

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Hey I'm trying to build a UIGestureRecognizer that allows me to spin a wheel on the screen. Imagine it like this:

[image]

Two gestures have to be detected: turning the wheel and spinning it. 
I've accomplished building a UIGestureRecognizer that recognizes turning the wheel, or rotating it, in other words. I'm also able to add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the wheel to detect if a spin gesture has occurred. However, I also want a gesture to be detected that looks like this:

1. The user rotates the wheel by panning over the screen
2. After panning, still with his finger on the screen, swiping fast and removing   the finger of the screen so that the wheel would spin

I tried using

`public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }`

to make them work simultaneously, but with no success. Also I think just connecting the both described GestureRecognizers wouldn't do the job.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code for the rotation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is going to be that when the pan starts, it will continue to be recognized as a pan gesture until the touch ends. So what you need to figure out is the velocity when the pan ends, and if you want to get fancier, project that velocity onto the perpendicular vector from the point relative to the centre of the view. This would involve some trigonometry, which I forget exactly but it would look something like this.

```
func pan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        ...

     if sender.state == .ended {
        let loc = sender.location(in: sender.view)
        let midpoint = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.bounds.width/2, y: sender.view!.bounds.height/2)
        let v = sender.velocity(in: sender.view)
        let p = CGPoint(x: midpoint.x - loc.x, y: midpoint.y - loc.y)

        let angle = atan(p.y/p.x)
        print(angle)
        let vProjection = v.y * cos((CGFloat.pi/2 - angle)) + v.x * cos(angle)
        print("moment: ", vProjection)

        let torque = p.hypotenuse() * vProjection
        wheel.rotate(with: torque)
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func hypotenuse() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y)
    }
}
```

I think I have an error in my trigonometry there. I would have to draw some diagrams, but it gives the general idea. wheel.rotate(with torque: CGFloat) would run an animation of the layer's transform to rotate it..

Comment: Although the values are not quite right yet, this works out pretty well already. The idea is great. Thank you really much!

Comment: you would probably be fine with just the velocity even. I didn't check the numbers just kinda scribbled it down with my limited algebra. Glad it's working!